Can't replace dead disk on mdadm raid1
The previous sdb died in my array, so I replaced it. When I try to add the new disk, I get the following error. I can't even add it as a spare.
# mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdb as 3: Invalid argument

# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sda[2]
      3906852864 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 12/30 pages [48KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
# mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add-spare /dev/sdb
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdb as 3: Invalid argument

# dmesg -T | tail | grep md
[Mon Aug  5 13:53:56 2024] md: sdb does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
[Mon Aug  5 13:53:56 2024] md: md_import_device returned -22

# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x9
     Array UUID : 1919e203:1242d469:d56eea7e:80667163
           Name : neverpi:1
  Creation Time : Thu Jul  8 17:29:41 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7813705728 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 3906852864 KiB (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 42492d32:9b6c9bda:93c938a2:20651bda

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug  5 13:49:02 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 8d549512 - correct
         Events : 0

I have tried clearing the first 100MB of the disk using dd, and I have tried using the zero superblock command. Where do I go from here?
This is a proxmox machine running
# uname -a
6.8.8-4-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PMX 6.8.8-4 (2024-07-26T11:15Z) x86_64 GNU/Linux


My immediate thought is drive size. Please edit your question to include the result from mdadm --examine /dev/sda.

I don't have a copy of it, but I did compare them visually and they looked the same. In the end I ended up creating a new array for SDB, rsyncing the data over to it, and then adding SDA to that, which worked fine. The new array is currently resyncing.
